# MySQL RDS Error: Host name could not be resolved: Name or service not known. What does it means? How to solve it?

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I have a RDS Mysql database with public access and for about 6 months everything has been okay connecting from my own computer, but today I started getting **Connection Lost Errors**. When I enter to mysql-error.log I see the same message over and over again:

```
2020-06-11T19:04:57.444383Z 14 [Warning] [MY-010056] [Server] Host name 'dsl-189-229-68-80-dyn.prod-infinitum.com.mx' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
2020-06-11T19:05:22.985440Z 15 [Warning] [MY-010056] [Server] Host name 'dsl-187-201-28-192-dyn.prod-infinitum.com.mx' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
2020-06-11T19:05:42.258746Z 19 [Warning] [MY-010056] [Server] Host name 'dsl-187-234-65-54-dyn.prod-infinitum.com.mx' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
```

I looked it up and tried several solutions but none seems to work. Here I explain some of which I already tried.

1. Activating skip_name_resolve in my mysql config file.
2. Checking that my RDS security group enables inbound and outbound traffic to 0.0.0.0/0
3. Activating performance schema and increasing the host_cache_size
4. Increasing the net_read_timeout and connect_timeout
5. Changing to my celular data and other wifi networks
6. Setting my username host to a specific IP Ex: 'username'@'192.134.234.24' instead of using % for the host

I have not been able to replicate it consistently, but it seems to happen more often when using complex queries (transactions). I am not sure if this may be a problem with my ISP or something like that because my web app which is connected locally to the mysql server does not have the same problem.